# Syntax error when trying to open .py file in powershell/cmd prompt

Tags: python, powershell, command-line, command-prompt

I am trying to open a sample file "helloworld.py" from Windows PowerShell. I changed the directory to the folder containing the file and checked with `ls` command that the file exists in the directory. I also checked that the c:/users/xxx/python38 is part of the system environment variables. When I tried to open the sample file with `python helloworld.py`, I get the following error :

```
PS D:\localfile> python helloworld.py
  File "helloworld.py", line 1
    Python 3.8.5 (tags/v3.8.5:580fbb0, Jul 20 2020, 15:57:54) [MSC v.1924 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

If I type only `python`, python is getting started in PowerShell and I am able to import packages, type python commands etc.

```
PS D:\localfile> python
Python 3.8.5 (tags/v3.8.5:580fbb0, Jul 20 2020, 15:57:54) [MSC v.1924 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print('hello')
hello
>>>
```

Edit:
Content of helloworld.py : print("hello world").
I need to execute this file in powershell, the reason why I am looking to execute .py files in powershell is I have some large `.py` files from GitHub which I need to run in command prompt/powershell with certain arguments.

Comment: What is the content of `helloworld.py`?

Comment: I don't use python in shell or command prompt, but you should try using `open helloworld.py` instead of just `helloworld.py`. I'm not sure, it may work, try it out

Comment: I think it is the nasty cp1252 problem. I created a file via cmd once and kept debugging for hours. Finally the problem was characters inserted by cp1252

Comment: "I am trying to open a sample file"—what do you mean by "open"? Are you trying to run the code? Edit it? Something else?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Content of the file is just print('hello world'). 
@Chris executing the file in powershell
@NMrocks can we supply arguments along with ```open filename.py```?

Comment: @user75252, please [edit] your question and add the contents of that file _there_ instead of in a comment.

Comment: Have you created the file via  print("hello world") > a.py in cmd/ powershell?

Comment: Can you try to write only helloworld.py  and press Enter, without Python prefix

Comment: @AlperenKantarcı not working

Comment: @user75252 Does command prompt also gives the same result with power shell? Also can you check your environment variables?

Comment: @AlperenKantarcı Cmmand Prompt gives the same result as powershell. Checked the envvironment variables, that is why python is working in both command prompt and powershell.

Comment: @VisheshMangla No, I created it using script and saved it in the folder.

Comment: you mean python idle or some ide? Knowing that is essential since there shouldn't be much problem otherwise.

Comment: @VisheshMangla created new script (Ctrl + N) from IDLE, in that script i wrote the code and saved it as helloworld.py.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49254893/how-to-change-default-character-encoding-for-python-idle . Maybe helpful.

Comment: @VisheshMangla both are UTF-8 in my case :(